# How does Google Maps intercept swipe/pinch gestures on laptop PCs with touchpads?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've noticed that Google Maps can intercept pinch gestures and swipe up/down gestures on my laptop PC which has a touchpad, on both Chrome and Firefox. What DOM event are they using? I tried experimenting with the [touch events API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) but it doesn't seem to be supported by my PC. (The MDN page refers to an example on jsfiddle.net: --- https://jsfaddle.net/Darbicus/z3Xdx/10/ but stackoverflow doesn't let me post links to jsfiddle.net --- but this doesn't seem to do anything with pinch/swipe gestures.)

Is there another event that it intercepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha -- I found it: it's the [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event).

```js
var c = document.getElementById('square');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.stroke();
c.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.deltaY);
});
```

```css
canvas#square {
  width: 500;
  height: 500;
}
```

```html
<html><body>
<canvas id="square" />
</body></html>
```